# Publishing an Azure Event Grid event via Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, azure-eventgrid

We're building a Vue SPA and using Axios to make API calls. We tried to extend the current methodology to post custom events to Azure Event Grid but get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://egtester.uksouth-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events?api-version=2018-01-01' from origin 'https://loving-chandrasekhar-bfd4c4.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My worry is that Event Grid has server side configuration that makes it incompatible with a browser based remote call like via axios.

We've created an MRE:

- [Github](https://github.com/nightingalehq/eventgrid-dummy-app)
- [Netlify Live demo](https://loving-chandrasekhar-bfd4c4.netlify.app/)
- The ARM for Event Grid and the JS are are the bottom of the Q

Some things we've checked/validated:

- [Docs on publishing custom events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/post-to-custom-topic#endpoint) outline the URL for the request and headers needed
- The code doesn't work on localhost or on netlify
- We have confirmed the endpoint is fine by running Postman queries
- The Event Grid is set to allow traffic from public IPs with no restrictions

**Does anyone know how to configure the axios request to work? Is axios an appropriate JS library to use in this instance?**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "topics_egtester_name": {
            "defaultValue": "egtester",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics",
            "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('topics_egtester_name')]",
            "location": "uksouth",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Basic"
            },
            "kind": "Azure",
            "identity": {
                "type": "None"
            },
            "properties": {
                "inputSchema": "EventGridSchema",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
                "disableLocalAuth": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
const eventGridKey = "3SErw+mCGtyvTWcVsa1lqd4iJiFW2IsUNmothj75J1A=";
const apiEndpoint = "https://egtester.uksouth-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api";

const eventGridApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiEndpoint,
  params: {
    "api-version": "2018-01-01"
  },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "aeg-sas-key": eventGridKey,
    },
});

function onSubmit() {
  let postData = {
    id: "9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d",
    eventType: "recordInserted",
    subject: "egtester/submission",
    eventTime: "2021-11-29T16:18:38.532Z",
    data: {
      preferredName: "Nikhil",
      familyName: "Kanukuntla",
      accepted: true,
      message: "Test Message",
      email: "nikhil.kanukuntla@nhq.com",
    },
  };

  eventGridApi
    .post("/events", postData)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the problem being related to the server-side configuration of the Azure Event Grid Server. Unfortunately, there is no way to alter this behavior. Also, with this approach you are exposing the key which is meant to be considered a secret.

The alternative would be to setup a simple service that can forward the request and respond with the right CORS headers. You could add an endpoint on your existing backend which can do this or leverage something like [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) / [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) to do the same. If you are already using Azure APIM, you could leverage this [policy example](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Forward%20Azure%20Event%20Grid%20Event.xml) as well.